# Models without database access in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I am currently learning how to use the [symfony2](http://symfony.com/) framework.

Going through the [cook book](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/index.html), I am starting to have a basic understanding of how everything fits together.

However, I have 2 questions regarding Entities, which I believe are models in the MVC pattern:

- In the documentation, there seems to be a lot of talk about entities using doctrine as ORM. If I have an entity/model that does not require any ORM, is this still considered an "entity"?
- In most tutorials I have seen, entities are often all thrown into a folder called "entities" under the application bundle. With many entities in an application, I feel that this can become quite messy and unorganized. How can I group and organize entities?

Cheers :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

regarding your question how to organize your model classes:

You may add Subfolders to "Entity" folder, then just follow that scructure in your namespace definition like:

```
<?php

namespace Acme\SampleBundle\Entity\Subfolder\EntityClass
```

regarding your question to work without orm: that's simple, just don't use it. 
your classes will behave like "normal" classes do..

But you will need some kind of interface to that, like EntityManager in Doctrine2, too.

I would always prefer the use of ORM/ODM..

That case I would just add a simple method to your entity class:

```
<?php

public function sendByEmail() {

// Do stuff
}
```

You dont have to persist (save to DB) stuff at all. Note that in symfony1.4 there was a `save()` method on entities. In Symfony2 stuff is saved through `$entityManager->persist($entity);`

Comment: What I meant by not using ORM is that some entities will not touch the database at all, instead they might read and write to files or some other storage.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know doctrine can do that. What about cases where I want my entity to process and validate some data, but instead of saving it, it should send the data off by email. In this case should I still use the EntityManager?

Answer (score 4):

Entities are models stored in a relational database. Documents are models stored in a document databases (MongoDB, for example).

If you don't want to bend your model to a particular namespace depending on what storage type you're using, here's what I suggest. Create the `Model` namespace for your model classes. If you choose to use a relational database, you extend your model class and put it into the `Entity` namespace, providing mapping information in an external file. If you later decide to move to a document database, you do the same, but use the `Document` namespace.

For a good example of this idea see [FOSUserBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle).

Answer (score 0):

When you tell that you have an entity/model that does not require any ORM, do you mean :

- The model is very simple so you can build your own database queries, OR :
- The data can be stored into regular files

?

If this is the first case, you can manage it as you want, but it is a good practice to use an ORM.

If this is the second case (as I assume), you still had better make Entities classes. Just you link to your data differently inside your classes. Instead of querying a database you search into files.

By doing that you conserve best practices, and if some day you want to switch to a DB model you will only have to change these classes.

To answer your second question, I have a 50+ entities model, and this doesn't make a mess. Inside the Entities classes I tell the user where to find the entity-relationship model, so this is clear.

Does this help you ?